# Samba: Forbid subdirectories?

Tags: samba

Is it possible to configure the smb.conf, so the samba-users can't create new subdirectories?

This is the part from my smb.conf:

```
[share]
browseable=yes
path=/media/data
public=yes
writable=yes
guest ok=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Since writable=yes, you will not be able to forbid creation of subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact way of separating files and folders.
What you may try is to rely on Windows ACL where "Modify" and "Write" give more control over traditional Unix file permission.
Having only "write" privilege forbid creating new files or directories, but can write, delete existing files or directories.
For Unix part, just give owner/group to other users/groups who are not relevant to the sharing directory or not mapped to SAMBA users/groups.